# Can't create a Postgis extension

Tags: postgresql, postgis

When I try to create a postgis extension the follow error is raised:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
ERROR:  could not load library "/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/lib/postgis-2.3.so": /usr/lib/liblwgeom-2.3.so.0: undefined symbol: GEOSClipByRect
```

For the installation, I have followed this guide: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/gis/install/geolibs/

Ubuntu: 16.04

Postgres: 9.5.8

Comment: question should be on [gis.se]

Comment: @EvanCarroll This is a definite case of overlapping topics, IMO: Postgres extensions, in general, are definitely on topic here; GIS applications, naturally, are on topic there. I'm not sure which site is most likely to attract a helpful answer.

Comment: I don't agree that this is on topic here. Or that GIS is naturally on topic here.

Comment: belongs on gis.se, just postgis installation

Comment: It's as much on topic here as any other Postgres extensions; there are [quite a lot of "create extension" questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpostgresql%5D+%22create+extension%22), and this seems very similar to them to me. The fact it's about GIS means it is **also** on topic on another site, and that site *might or not* elicit a better answer, depending on if the necessary expertise is more GIS-related or more general Postgres/devops-related.

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed the postgis package?

sudo apt install postgresql-9.5-postgis-2.3

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I did install it.

Comment: So what is in /usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/ directory?

Answer (score -2):

Learn to Google, [a direct rip off of GIS.SE's answer by PolyGeo](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/227266/6052)

> This error happens if you compiled PostGIS **with a newer version of GEOS than what you have in your install path.**
>
> If you installed your PostGIS from a package, you probably just need to do an apt-get update, apt-get upgrade

You can find a bug [report of it here](https://trac.osgeo.org/postgis/ticket/3423)

Comment: Yes, i have seen this. And do an update and upgrade with no results

Comment: I am downvoting this answer, because it is unnecessarily rudely worded, and since it's a link to another SE could have been added as a comment with a link.

Comment: @IMSoP it is the answer, you don't have to like it. The problem is he's not building for his own local version of GEOS. Perhaps he upgraded and forgot to restart. Perhaps he has two versions installed. Either way, you only get this error on a version mismatch.